# Scene name as output name in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene

Is it possible to set the scene name in the output properties in the VSE to the scene name?

On [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/t/output-render-file-name/633891) I read that `%S` should be the scene name. When I enter this in the output section as `/path/to/file/%S.mp4` the file is named "%S.mp4". I am probably doing this wrong, but I wonder if this even possible to name the file in this location.

What I want to do:
I use blender to create short animations for presentations. To be able to continue with the animation where the last scene stopped I copy the scene and delete everything I do not need. The filename is copied over. The filename is not changed so when you have more than one scene, the output of the second scene will overwrite the one of the first scene when you forget to change the filename.

Comment: that's a very good question. in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/properties/output.html) it mentions only about the #### syntax but nothing about %s or other syntax. I wonder if anyone knows something.

Comment: Have you tried to look for add-ons doing what you need? https://blenderdepot.netlify.app/addons?search=file%20name&page=1&sort=popular

Comment: @tintwotin at first I thought %S was a feature in blender that is broken now but then I found out it was from the vray-blender addon. and I found [this addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/object/oscurart_tools.html). I was hoping this feature was a built-in in blender. i guess not. so blender's file output only supports the # syntax right? then I guess this issue is "solved"

Comment: Have you tried setting the output to `'/path/to/file/' + bpy.context.scene.name + '.mp4'` ?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie What doesn't?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Are you setting `context.scene.render.filepath`?

Comment: @AnsonSavage the expression `'/path/to/file/' + bpy.context.scene.name + '.mp4'` will not work in the *Output Properties'* *Output Name* field because this field does not accept python expressions. Have you tried it? :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Oh, I see what you're saying. Okay, well are you open to an addon or python script that will set that for you?

Comment: Yeah addon is fine. I just wanted to confirm if the *Output Name* field really only accepted the # syntax with no other possible syntaxes. But I think the dev team really ought to consider changing this field to accept python expressions XD

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with Python by setting the `context.scene.render.filepath` setting. Here's an example mini addon that does this by putting a button called "Set Render Path" in the output panel of the properties editor. It works by getting the file directory that the user has already set to render to and then replacing the name of the file with the name of the scene (`bpy.context.scene.name`).

```
import bpy
import os

def get_file_directory_from_path(filepath):
    return os.path.dirname(bpy.path.abspath(filepath)) + os.path.sep

class ButtonPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Set Path Panel"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "output"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("render.set_render_path_and_render")

class SetRenderPathThenRender(bpy.types.Operator):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "render.set_render_path_and_render"
    bl_label = "Set Render Path"

    def execute(self, context):
        context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(
            get_file_directory_from_path(
                context.scene.render.filepath
            ),
            bpy.context.scene.name + '.mp4'
        )
#        bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ButtonPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SetRenderPathThenRender)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SetRenderPathThenRender)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ButtonPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

This assumes that the file extension has already been set to .mp4 by the user. Optionally, if you'd like to render after clicking this button, you can uncomment the line with `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)`.

Comment: yes this is a good solution. since the user has to press the render button anyway, they could press another "render" button in the addon that automatically set's the filepath before rendering :) thanks for sharing!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yeah! Thanks :))