Command line render use scene name
Hello :) is there any expression for naming the render with the scene name ? something like that :
blender -b "F:\Test_Anim\Test_Anim.blend" -o //Render/<scene_name>/<scene_name>_### -S Sphere -a

blender -b "F:\Test_Anim\Test_Anim.blend" -o //Render/<scene_name>/<scene_name>_### -S Cube -a

Thank you

How do you know what commands to run for rendering with command line with Blender?

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#render-options

related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269699/scene-name-as-output-name-in-vse

@HarryMcKenzie I saw this, but my knowledge in python are very limited. I don't want any button, juste lunch the script and the name applied for every scenes..

So I find a solution.
I created 1 script to auto fill the output path witch use the scenes name to create a subfolder and name the export files :
import bpy
import os

blend_filepath = bpy.data.filepath

project_dir = os.path.dirname(blend_filepath)

parent_dir = os.path.dirname(project_dir)

render_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, '04_RENDER')

if not os.path.exists(render_dir):
    os.makedirs(render_dir)

new_folder_name = "NameExemple"
new_folder_path = os.path.join(render_dir, new_folder_name)

if not os.path.exists(new_folder_path):
    os.makedirs(new_folder_path)

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:

    scene_name = scene.name

    render_path = os.path.join(new_folder_path,f"{scene_name}\{scene_name}_###")

    scene.render.filepath = render_path

Then i created a script to create a text file with the command to lunch the render via the command line :
import bpy
import os

blend_file_path = bpy.data.filepath

file_path = bpy.path.abspath("//render_all_scenes.txt")

with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
        file.write(f"blender -b {blend_file_path}  -S {scene.name} -a\n")
        file.write("\n")

